# Devise + Rail-API. Manually signing in users doesn't set the current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-api

I'm testing some gems since I'm about to create an API for a iOS app. This time I'm using Rails-API and Devise for user registrations. I followed this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ricbermo/8675056) that I forked from a forked-forked gist, I did some changes and a User can register and login, but, when I use `before_filter :authenticate_api_user!` on a controller, after login the current_api_user is nil. According to [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L63) from the source code of divise, I a use devise_for inside a namespace then everything changes. This is my code.

Routes:

```
Todo::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    devise_for :users
    resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :videos, only: [:create]
    get "/users/show", to: "users#show"
  end
end
```

app/api/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Api::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_api_user!, except: [:create]
  before_filter :ensure_user_login_param_exists, only: [:create]
  # before_filter :ensure_email_param_exists, only: [:create]
  # before_filter :ensure_password_param_exists, only: [:create]
  respond_to :json

  def create
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user_login][:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(params[:user_login][:password])
      sign_in(:api_user, resource)
      #resource.ensure_authentication_token!
      render json: { success: true, email: current_api_user.email }, status: :created
      return
    end
    invalid_login_attempt
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

app/api/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Api::RegistrationsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render json: user.as_json(email: user.email), status: :created
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render json: user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

I hope someone can help me. By the way I'm really accepting any advice about the best way to create an API using rails. It's my first time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: for authenticate user first time in your app you should verify credentials and then generate and return a token . this will catch by the iphone app and will be saved in memory .now iphone app will send this auth token for authentication

Comment: and then `def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.where(authentication_token: params[:auth_token]).first
  end` in your controller or helper

Comment: So, it'd be better not to use Devise, since it has many features that I won't use here and register the users manually with a `authentication_token` column, which value will be generated automatically after_save. Am i right?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/lhalff/has_secure_password. you can use devise as well. just use feature of devise you need .

Comment: i can help you in setting up the API in rails .so if you feel any problem my skype handle is nitinjain2021

Comment: I'm with the same problem... =(